# How can you predict the power an electrical generator (alternator) produces?

Tags: power-supply, power, generator, alternator

We have to design an electrical alternator in a multiphysics software, but we can't seem to figure out how to deduce the power it will produce. We need to charge a capacitor to 1000 joules (at 2000V) with it and want to know how long this will take. However, we the only output from Comsol is the induced voltage.

To go to 2000 Volts we attached the following stages to our generator:

Alternator --- full-bridge rectifier --- 5V-12V step-up --- 12V-2000V step-up --- Capacitor

How can we calculate the power that is produced to deduce the charging time of the capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

The power (and energy) depend on the load.  Neglecting losses, if the load is just a capacitor the energy to charge it from 0V up to 2000V is 1/2CV^2.  That same amount of energy will be dissipated by the inherent resistance.  So, source will provide energy 2E to charge cap to E.

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing an AC generator, you fist select a machine type, presumably a permanent synchronous generator in this case. Then you determine what you will drive it with. Perhaps you will crank it by hand. Then you estimate how much power you might be able to produce to turn the crank. That might be 100 watts. You need to estimate how fast you can turn the crank. That might be 120 RPM. Then you might want to look at some existing designs and determine how difficult it might be to design a generator that will produce 5 volts at 120 RPM. That might lead you to determine that you need to mechanically increase the cranking speed. There will be some power loss in the mechanical drive train, so you might have 90 watts mechanical input to the generator.

Then you design the generator. The generator will have losses that you should be able to estimate when doing the design. The rectifier will also have losses. I suspect that  you would be doing quite well if your generator is 50% efficient. The rectifier will probably be 60% efficient. For 5 volts output after the forward voltage drop across the diodes, what does the input voltage need to be?

Two stages of of DC to DC step-up conversion will have a lot of lost power. If you are going to purchase those, see if you can get the efficiency from the seller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The application would be as an linear alternator for power from wave energy. Is there any way to work out the power without using the efficiencies? Also, can you guess the efficiency of your design using the multiphysics software? Or only by using literature as a reference? 

We found a paper that just adds a 4 Ohm resistor in series, but this seems wildy arbitrary (is this related to the resistance from the rectifier/transformers?

Comment: Everything that you have said about this system indicates that the design will have a very low efficiency. That means that the efficiency will be the most important factor in determining the output.